# Adyen - What are the disadvantages using Rest APIs instead SDK for mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, payment, mobile-application, adyen

Adyen provide both Rest API's and SDK's to integrate in mobile apps. I could not find any strong reason why one should use SDK but API's. Asking here in case I am missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adyen SDKs are for relatively smaller merchants as the SDKs will take care of the rendering and handling of the request and response. It has all the options such as recurring, payouts etc. The PCI compliancy is also mitigated if you are using checkout API + SDKs.

APIs are for merchants that requires quite some customizations and want to handle almost everything on their side and are generally PCI compliant (raw card data handling) and requires quite some development time as well.

I hope this answer your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times SDKs are just a simplified or Use Case tailored abstraction to the API. 
So if you don’t need the full customizable power provided by the API you can simply use the SDK and you don’t need to handle API Calls,Error Handling, Writing own methods etc. by yourself.